# how to use PageRemote in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

my  code is below:

```cs
public class Lib
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [PageRemote(PageHandler = "IsKeyExists", HttpMethod = "Get")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

in the Create page model:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetIsKeyExistsAsync(string key)
{
    var query = _context.Lib.Any(l => l.Key == key);
    if (query)
    {
        return new JsonResult($"Key {key} exists");
    }

    return new JsonResult(true);
}
```

When I Debug the code, `OnGetIsKeyExistsAsync` always get the parameter key of value null.

I find the request in browe is:

```
https://localhost:44377/Libs/Create?handler=IsKeyExists&Lib.Key=xx
```

I test with `PostMan`, and modify the parameter name with Key, and everything runs ok.

```
https://localhost:44377/Libs/Create?handler=IsKeyExists&Key=xx
```

I don't want to modify my page model to bind another string value,and how to make it work with `Lib.Key`?

Maybe this question is not about remote page, only relation to `razor` page or `asp.net core`.

Comment: What is your razor page view like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url generate the parameter's name depends on your input name.

The reason why your url will generate the url like `https://localhost:44377/Libs/Create?handler=IsKeyExists&Lib.Key=xx` is that `asp-for` would generate the name by default:

```
<input asp-for="Lib.Key"  />
```

Generate the html:

```
<input type="text" id="Lib_Key" name="Lib.Key" data-val="true" data-val-remote="'Key' is invalid." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Key" data-val-remote-type="Get" data-val-remote-url="/?handler=IsKeyExists" data-val-required="The Key field is required." value="">
```

If you want to work with `Lib.Key`,the parameter you received in your handler should be an object like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetIsKeyExistsAsync(Lib Lib)
```

If your do not want to change your handler,you need to specify the name like below:

```
<input asp-for="Lib.Key" name="key" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I modify the function OnGetIsKeyExistsAsync(Lib lib) and it works well.